# Calculate the mean score of every row for a specific time

Tags: r

Using as input a data frame like this one:

```
data.frame(timespand = c("2020-12","2020-12","2019-06","2020-12","2019-06","2019-06"), c1 = c(0.4,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.5,1.2), c2 = c(2.1,3.4,5.2,1,0.3,0.4))
```

How is it possible to receive for the same timespand for every column and have a melt results such as this expected output:

```
column timespand mean
c1 2020-12 0.73
c2 2020-12 2.17
c1 2020-06 0
c2 2020-06 0
c1 2019-12 0
c2 2019-12 0
c1 2019-06 0.6
c2 2019-06 1.97
```

Comment: @akrun yes it is correct the 0.33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and do the group by `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('c'), names_to = 'column') %>% 
     group_by(column, timespand) %>%
     summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')%>% 
     arrange(desc(timespand))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  column timespand  mean
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
1 c1     2020-12   0.333
2 c2     2020-12   2.17 
3 c1     2019-06   0.6  
4 c2     2019-06   1.97
```

---

If we need to expand with missing 'timespand' use `complete`

```
library(zoo)
df1 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('c'), names_to = 'column') %>% 
     group_by(column, timespand) %>%
     summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')%>% 
     mutate(timespand = as.Date(as.yearmon(timespand))) %>% 
     complete(column, timespand = seq(min(timespand), max(timespand),
        by = '6 month'), fill = list(mean = 0)) %>% 
     mutate(timespand = format(timespand, '%Y-%m')) %>%
     arrange(desc(timespand))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  column timespand  mean
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
1 c1     2020-12   0.333
2 c2     2020-12   2.17 
3 c1     2020-06   0    
4 c2     2020-06   0    
5 c1     2019-12   0    
6 c2     2019-12   0    
7 c1     2019-06   0.6  
8 c2     2019-06   1.97
```

Comment: actually is it also possible to and the zero time spands like 2019-12 and 2020-06 please see the update expected output if it helps